# How do Hayabusa-2's DCAM's work? (detachable cameras)

Tags: hayabusa2

The screenshot below from the JAXAxxx video [Mission Control Live: Hayabusa2 SCI Operation](https://youtu.be/Lh4iFyMRWZg) shows a diagram with DCAM3, a detachable camera that has the lucky job of watching the impact on Ryugu while Hyabusa-2 retreats to a safe distance.

How does this Deployable Camera (DCAM 3) work?

For example:

- Does it have an attitude control system to maintain its gaze while waiting for the even to happen?
- Does it have propulsion for translation as well?
- Solar or battery power?
- Does Hayabusa-2 retrieve it afterwards for the data, or for reuse?
- Does it use its power to live-broadcast

---

[image: Hayabusa-2 Deployable Camera]

[image: [Hayabusa-2 Deployable Camera]